# DecisionTreeClassificationModel - how to parse and visualize decision tree in PySpark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, decision-tree

I have a model fitted by **DecisionTreeClassifier** (class **DecisionTreeClassificationModel**) and need to parse it's tree nodes in order to visualize a subset or whole tree, but it seems that methods available in PySpark API are very limited.
For example - I'd like to take node *N* and get its parent or all the leaves. 
Would this possible using PySpark API? So far all I can do is to call:

```
model.toDebugString()
```

and parse the string to recreate the tree structure.

I saw that [Java API](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/ml/classification/DecisionTreeClassificationModel.html) provides more options, but I don't know how to use it in PySpark script.

What I also found on the web is that there is a [spark-tree-plotting](https://github.com/julioasotodv/spark-tree-plotting) package that even visualizes the tree, but I got some failures when trying to install it (seems that it is not maintained anymore).

I would appreciate any tips on how to efficiently parse the decision tree returned by the model.